# How to model M-M relationship with differnce variation

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database, informix

If  the user requirement mock-up to something like that :

[image]
1-`Company (id -name -etc)`

and each Company has (`Iron,Cement`) entered in specific (`month-year`) .

The `Iron` has `local sales` and the `Cement` has `Exporting`.

Each `Company` has (`Start balance`) for (`Iron,Cement`) entered only once .

How to model something like that ?

Comment: Are `Exporting` and `LocalSales` the same data type in sql? Is it just the naming issue?

Comment: No they are two different meaning , actually `Cement`  has `local sales` also but `Iron` doesn't has `exporting` field

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but are they essentially both integers?

Comment: @JanezKuhar : both of them decimal

Comment: Is `Balance start` in any relation with `Local Sales`, `Exporting` or `Production`?

Comment: @JanezKuhar : No not at all ,they are totally different forms .`Local Sales, Exporting or Production` belongs to `Quantity` meaning and `Balance start` entered by the user only once for (Cement,Iron) for each Company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understood your domain one could do something like this:

```
Company(id, name, ...) // PK = id
Material(id, name) // PK = id 
Entry(idCompany, idMaterial, month-year, production, localSales, exporting) // PK = idCompany, idMaterial, month-year
Initial(idCompany, idMaterial, date, balanceStart) PK = idCompany, idMaterial, date
```

If you create your tables this way you can use one table to store data for both cement and iron. You can then write a custom `VIEW` to display only relevant columns for each material.